# Find and mark center point of JPG/TIF images?

Tags: images, photos, layers

Is there a way for me to easily find and mark with a dot the center point of an image/photo?

I have no specific requirements for what software to do this (though I currently only have access to Gimp and Photoshop CS3, I am willing to install others).

I prefer solutions that allow the following (but they're not hard requirements):

(1) I prefer it to work on Windows, Macs, and Linux machines.

(2) I prefer to mark the center point "non-destructively", i.e. I still like to have the original image without any marks (*maybe* through layers?).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/). It has packages for Windows, OS X and Linux, although you may have to build from source using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) for OS X.

Once installed, at a comand prompt type:
 `composite -gravity center small-center-image.jpg original-image.jpg: new-image.jpg`

This will overlay the `small-center-image.jpg` over the original image and save it under a new filename. Further examples of this particular command can be found [here.](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/composite.php)

This is just barely scratching the surface of what the ImageMagick toolset can do. A full set of HTML documentation pages will be available on your computer with the install of the package.

Comment: I installed ImageMagick via MacPorts in OS X, but got the error "composite: no decode delegate for this image format". What does that mean?

Comment: The documentation is apparently wrong - remove the colon after the orignal-image name. Then it should work. Refer to this http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=18515 for details.

Comment: Ah yes that did it, and the compositing works fine now. Thank you for the answer!